# Custom handling for small portion of JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a 2MB-4MB JSON string coming from a server, which I have no control over (either the server or the incoming JSON), so the format of the string is what it is.

I used jsonschema2pojo-core artifactId from org.jsonschema2pojo groupId to auto-generate my Java classes from the JSON string. It all works well until I get to a particular portion of the JSON string that I need to be handled differently from what the JSON indicates it represents.

The portion of the JSON string I need to handle differently is laid out like this (in particular, it's the "class6" class.

```
{
    "class1": {
        "class2": {
            "class3": [{
                    "class4": {
                        "class5": [{
                                "class6": {
                                    "str1": 2,
                                    "str2": 3,
                                    "str3": 2,
                                    "str4": 3,
                                    "str5": 2
                                }
                            }, {
                                "class6": {
                                    "str1": 2,
                                    "str2": 3,
                                    "str3": 2,
                                    "str4": 3,
                                    "str5": 2
                                }
                            }, {
                                "class6": {
                                    "str1": 2,
                                    "str2": 3,
                                    "str3": 2,
                                    "str4": 3,
                                    "str5": 2
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                }
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

The number of items in class 6 is variable, as are their names; the above names and counts are just illustrative.

The Java generator spit out a `Class6` class, with a `Long` named str1, a `Long` named str2, etc.

What I *actually* need is a `Class6` class where I have either a map or 2D array (doesn't really matter which, but I was aiming for a HashMap) where str1 is the name of a `String` rather than a class, with the `int` on the right side of the `:` being a value associated with it (hence a HashMap).

I had a hard time finding out how to do this (deserializer vs type adapter?), but what I eventually ended up with is this:

```
public class Class6TypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Class6> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, Class6 t) throws IOException {
        //I only deserialize, never serialize
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Class6 read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        Class6 class6 = new Class6();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
                reader.beginObject();
            }

            String name = null;
            if (reader.hasNext() && (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NAME)) {
                name = reader.nextName();
            }

            Integer value = null;
            if (reader.hasNext() && (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NUMBER)) {
                value = reader.nextInt();
            }

            if (reader.hasNext() && (reader.peek() == JsonToken.END_OBJECT)) {
                reader.endObject();
            }

            if (name != null && value != null) {
                class6.getMap().put(name, value);
            }
        }
        return class6;
    }
}
```

I was getting `Exception`s that helpfully referenced my class as I was working out the details of how I'm supposed to use a `TypeAdapter` (hard to find), but after I worked all of them out, I'm now getting an `Exception` that doesn't reference my `TypeAdapter` anymore, but rather my call to `Gson#fromJson()` in general, with the Exception details as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NAME at line 1 column 1241675 path $.class1.class2.class3[0].class4.class5[0].class6
```

My `#read()` method seems to return ok after building the `HashMap` (33 items in the real usage), but it barfs right after the return. So I know my TypeAdapter is messing Gson up now when it tries to deserialize things after my special handling, but I'm not sure how, as the exception isn't referencing anything specific enough for me to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where my inability to find good information on TypeAdapters in GSON comes in, along with my lack of scrutiny of the API documentation. This line:

```
        if (reader.hasNext() && (reader.peek() == JsonToken.END_OBJECT)) {
            reader.endObject();
        }
```

fails to return true because `hasNext()` is false when the end of the object has been reached, so `reader.endObject()` never gets called. I moved the called to end the object to right after the `while` loop, and it works.